# security:filter-chain pattern match url have symbol '?'

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-mvc

- I want use spring filter this url: 
  `http://localhost:9280/spring-filter/login.html?collection=abc#/input`
- I use code filter 
  `<security:filter-chain pattern="/*/input" filters="collectionLoginFilter" />` but not working.
- If I don't have symbol '?' in url `http://localhost:9280/spring-filter/login.html/input`, it will working.
- **Question**: I want use symbol '?'. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can. Spring only analyze the URL before '?'. Anything after '?' is parameter

Check [spring-security documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#request-matching), specifically these line

> Un-normalized requests are automatically rejected by default, and path parameters and duplicate slashes are removed for matching purposes

Comment: `Anything after '?' is parameter` I know but in url, parameter finish when I use '#'. <br />Thanks for your help!